# Is there a quick way for checking whether a date lies within n days(say 7) from a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, list, date, datetime

I'm working with the following dataset:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2016-01-04 |
| 2016-01-05 |
| 2016-01-06 |
| 2016-01-07 |
| 2016-01-08 |

and a list `holidays = ['2016-01-01','2016-01-18'....'2017-11-23','2017-12-25']`

**Objective:** Create a column indicating whether a particular date is within +- 7 days of **any** holiday present in the list.

**Mock output:**

| Date | Within a week of Holiday |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-01-04 | 1 |
| 2016-01-05 | 1 |
| 2016-01-06 | 1 |
| 2016-01-07 | 1 |
| 2016-01-08 | 0 |

I'm working with a lot of date records and thus trying to find a quick(most optimized) way to do this.

**My Current Solution:**

One way I figured to do this quickly would be to create another list with **only the unique dates** for my desired duration(say 2 years). This way, I can implement a simple solution with ***2 for loops*** to check if a date is within +-7days of a holiday, and it wouldn't be computationally heavy as both lists would be relatively small(730 unique dates and ~20 dates in the holiday list).
Once I have my desired list of dates, all I have to do is run a single check on my 'Date' column to see if that date is a part of this new list I created. However, any suggestions to do this even quicker?

Comment: Use the `any()` function

Comment: Your idea sounds great.  But instead of using a `list` for the range of dates around the holidays, use a `set` - it's faster to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn holidays into a DataFrame and then [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof) with a tolerance of 6 days:

```
new_df = pd.merge_asof(df, holidays, left_on='Date', right_on='Holiday',
                       tolerance=pd.Timedelta(days=6))
new_df['Holiday'] = np.where(new_df['Holiday'].notnull(), 1, 0)
new_df = new_df.rename(columns={'Holiday': 'Within a week of Holiday'})
```

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

holidays = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-18']),
                        columns=['Holiday'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07',
             '2016-01-08']
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

new_df = pd.merge_asof(df, holidays, left_on='Date', right_on='Holiday',
                       tolerance=pd.Timedelta(days=6))
new_df['Holiday'] = np.where(new_df['Holiday'].notnull(), 1, 0)
new_df = new_df.rename(columns={'Holiday': 'Within a week of Holiday'})
print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
        Date  Within a week of Holiday
0 2016-01-04                         1
1 2016-01-05                         1
2 2016-01-06                         1
3 2016-01-07                         1
4 2016-01-08                         0
```

---

Or turn Holdiays into a np datetime array then [`broadcast`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) subtraction across the 'Date' Column, compare the `abs` to 7 days, and see if there are [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html#numpy-any) matches:

```
holidays = np.array(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-18']).astype('datetime64')

df['Within a week of Holiday'] = (
        abs(df['Date'].values - holidays[:, None]) < pd.Timedelta(days=7)
).any(axis=0).astype(int)
```

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

holidays = np.array(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-18']).astype('datetime64')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07',
             '2016-01-08']
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Within a week of Holiday'] = (
        abs(df['Date'].values - holidays[:, None]) < pd.Timedelta(days=7)
).any(axis=0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
        Date  Within a week of Holiday
0 2016-01-04                         1
1 2016-01-05                         1
2 2016-01-06                         1
3 2016-01-07                         1
4 2016-01-08                         0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Henry. This was a very well explained and elegant solution to my problem. Will definitely upvote your answer. 
Also, if I may ask. how do you keep yourself up to date/aware of all these functions in python? There seem to be a lot of useful functions in python, and if only a person could connect the dots to it -> superhuman abilities like yourself.

Comment: Done, thanks Henry! I'll continue to build various POVs on my problems, and perhaps someday I'll be able answer a few questions here 

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Sample:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-01-04',
  1: '2016-01-05',
  2: '2016-01-06',
  3: '2016-01-07',
  4: '2016-01-08'}})
```

**Code:**

```
def get_date_range(holidays):
    h = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in holidays]
    h = [pd.date_range(x - pd.DateOffset(6), x + pd.DateOffset(6)) for x in h]
    h = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for y in h for x in y]
    return h

df['Within a week of Holiday'] = df['Date'].isin(get_date_range(holidays))*1
```

**Result:**

```
Out[141]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
Name: Within a week of Holiday, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

make a `function` that calculate date with `+- 7` days and check if calculated date is in holidays so return `True` else `False` and apply that function to `Data frame`

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
holidays = ['2016-01-01','2016-01-18','2017-11-23','2017-12-25']
def holiday_present(date):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    for i in range(-7,7):
        datte = (date - datetime.timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        if datte in holidays:
            return True
    return False

data = {
    "Date":[
"2016-01-04",
"2016-01-05",
"2016-01-06",
"2016-01-07",
"2016-01-08"]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Within a week of Holiday"] = df["Date"].apply(holiday_present).astype(int)
```

**Output:**

```
    Date    Within a week of Holiday
0   2016-01-04  1
1   2016-01-05  1
2   2016-01-06  1
3   2016-01-07  1
4   2016-01-08  0
```